# Reference Elements in Child Lightning Component from Parent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to be able to reference an element in a Lightning component that's nested in a parent component.

**Child component (named "MyChildComponent")**

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:input aura:id="childComponentElement"
                     type="text"
                     label="My Child Component Input" />
</aura:component>
```

**Parent component**

```
<aura:component>
    <c:MyChildComponent aura:id="childComponent" />
</aura:component>
```

I'm trying to reference the child from the parent controller.js so I can hide the input at certain times:

**Parent Controller.js**

```
var myChildComponentElement = component.find("childComponentElement ");
$A.util.addClass(myChildComponentElement , "slds-hide");
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: why don't you wrap it in div's and assign an aura:id ?

Comment: @glls the child element does have an aura:id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although below method is possible as of today in AURA, this is **anti
>   pattern** according to LWC
>   DOM access containment - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_locker_dom

Since both parent and child components are in same namespace, you can modify the elements inside child component from parent like below :

```
    let childComponent = component.find("childComponent");
    let childComponentElement = childComponent.find("childComponentElement");
    $A.util.addClass(childComponentElement , "slds-hide");
```

However you cannot access elements inside `childComponentElement` since it is of `lightning` namespace.

---

A better approach (future proof) would be to use [public methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm):

Parent.JS:

```
let childComponent = component.find("childComponent");
childComponent.toggleInput("childComponentElement");
```

Child.cmp:

```
<aura:component >

    <aura:attribute name="element" type="String" />

    <aura:method name="toggleInput" action="{!c.toggleInput}" >
        <aura:attribute name="element" type="String" />
    </aura:method>

    <lightning:input aura:id="childComponentElement"
                     type="text"
                     label="My Child Component Input" />

</aura:component>
```

Child.JS:

```
toggleInput : function(component, event, helper) {
    let element = event.getParam("arguments").element;
    $A.util.toggleClass(component.find(element), "slds-hide");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a component's internal components from the outside, nor can a child component directly manipulate its parent component. This is a security feature built in to Aura, that allows potentially untrusted components from different developers to remain secure within the same page/app. You would need to either hide the component completely by applying the class to it, or modify the child component to allow a class or attribute to be set to hide the input field.

Comment: It is actually possible. Given in answer how.

Comment: @salesforce-sas You should not rely on this behavior. The [documentation](https://github.com/aurajs/aura/blob/master/README.md) for Aura says *A component represents a unit of a page. Each component is independent. This means that they know nothing about each other. To make them communicate, a Publish/Subscribe (Mediator) pattern is used.* While it is technically true that you can currently do so within the same namespace, this is not future-compatible. All components should use the Publish/Subscribe model for communication, and not attempt to directly modify each other.

Comment: @salesforce-sas Also, this behavior is not LWC compatible at all. While your answer demonstrates that it is currently possible, it is only a "happy coincidence" that it does so for the moment. There's also another doc I can't find right now that talks about isolation of components in a future release. Until/unless the docs *specifically* tell us this is allowed, we have to assume that all the existing documentation, which tells us *not* to do this, is correct.

Comment: In https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm, we are trying to directly get attribute values from source (even aura component). What I did is a little extension of same. Do you think this is not valid?